# Odometer not taking effect in wordpress page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, odometer

I am trying to make a youtube views live counter, I reached a step where I can get the views every 5 seconds and update it on the wordpress page.

The problem is that I want to implement an odometer effect, so I am using this
https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/

I am importing the css in the head, and the script after the body. The div has class 'odometer' but its not taking effect.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: ```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-car.css">
</head>
<body>
<p id="odometer" class="odometer">60846013</p>
</body>
<script src="http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/odometer.js"></script>
```

Comment: Put the code in your question and only what matters, we can't spend hours watching your full code. It's called the [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-car.css">
```

Note the `https://` at the start of the href.

If you viewed your console with your current code you would have seen a 404 on the css file, as

`github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-car.css`
is effectively saying:
`http://yourdomain.com/yourfilepath/github.hubspot.com/odometer/themes/odometer-theme-car.css`

For the same reason, you need to do the same with your JS too:

```
 <script src="https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/odometer.js"></script>
```

Console is your friend.

Sidenote, you might want to serve the CSS file locally (download it to your site's directory and then use a local path) rather than rely on a remote URL.

Comment: I did as you suggested, but the function still doesn't work, there is no animation at all

Comment: you need to do the same for the JS.

Comment: @AhmedHani did this (including doing it for the JS)  fix the issue? If so, suggest ticking the answer to help others.

Answer (score 0):

I did have a similar problem with gatsby a while back but if you serve the ccss so it isn't remote it could help